# In Azure Web App Deployment Center, getting "No Item Found" for repository when deploying through Bitbucket

Tags: reactjs, azure, deployment, bitbucket

When selecting BitBucket for Source Control, I am able to click my name for the "Team" option, however when I click the "Repository" option it says "No Item Found".

It is a private repo and I am the admin for the repo.

Comment: Did you go through [this steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment#deploy-continuously-from-bitbucket)?

Comment: @Jayendran yes I did with no help. Ended up resolving it by going to resources.azure.com then subscriptions -> Pay As You Go -> Resource Groups -> "My Resource" -> Providers -> Microsoft.web -> sites -> "My Site" -> Sourcecontrols -> web and then editing and Patching the JSON with my bitbucket URL. Unorthodox fix but it worked.

Comment: Seems weird.. You can then provide your own answer here and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions -> Pay As You Go -> Resource Groups -> "My Resource" -> Providers -> Microsoft.web -> sites -> "My Site" -> Sourcecontrols -> web and then edit and Patching the JSON with your bitbucket URL.